# How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier

Tags: spring-batch

I get error stated in Title  using following job conifuration file with ClassifierCompositItemWriter.  Why is it not finding BackToBackPatternClassifier?  I'm really new to this.

I'm using 
 - Spring-core version 3.2.2.RELEASE
 - Spring batch version 2.2.0.RELEASE

> 

```
<bean id="domain" class="com.my.OneData" />

<job id="readAsString" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="theItemReader" writer="compositeWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="theItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/inputs/ad_usage_sample.csv" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"></property>
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="compositeWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="classifier">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
            <property name="routerDelegate">
                <bean class="com.my.LineClassifier" />
            </property>
            <property name="matcherMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="abc" value-ref="fileItemWriter1" />
                    <entry key="xyz" value-ref="fileItemWriter2" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fileItemWriter1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/outputs/oneLouderOutput3.csv" />
    <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fileItemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/outputs/oneLouderOutput3.csv" />
    <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar problem and found that I had to change the package of the Classifier from

```
org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier
```

to

```
org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier
```

i.e. remove the *batch*

I am also using `spring-retry-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: this should fix it. here is dependency for spring retry 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

`BackToBackPatternClassifier` (and `Classifier`) is defined is `spring-retry` module and probably you need to include its jar in your classpath (I can't check now, but latest version is `spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE`)